# Error:{"name":"GooglesigninError","code":10} in react native while login in AWS through google

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, google-signin

I'm working on AWS through google But while login in google i'm getting exception after the i login i have genrated the google-services.json. But also the sha1 i have put right in firebase and google console as well. but after login in google. i'm getting error.

I have followed this link https://github.com/patw0929/react-native-amplify-cognito-example

```
   export const loginGoogle = () => {
   Alert.alert("id");

 return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
 Alert.alert("13");
 const user = await GoogleSignin.signIn()


 .catch(error => {

  Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(error))
```

I want the user details after login. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: You must change the SHA1 key of your client ID to the Android Debug Key store.

Comment: Yes,i already changed it but nothing is happening.

Comment: you checked the latest vesion of SDK, tools, Google PlayService, Google Repository

Comment: I'm working on react native First i enter my project in firebase and get the google.json-services and enter the same sha1 key which i have entered in the google console. then i go do google console and get the Clientid and secreat id and put that in my project but the problem is i'm getting different client id in google-services from firebase and diffrent in google console but same sha1 key i have entered in both

Answer (score 0):

You have to check.

1. Did you forget to upload the SHA-1 fingerprint release key store to
   the Google/firebase Console?
2. Did you add two SHA1 keys to the Firebase console?
3. In addition to adding the correct SHA-1 for both debug and release
   keys, you have also downloaded the new `google-services.json`.